# Print all permutations with some constraints

Tags: java, performance, combinatorics

I've the following problem:

> Print all valid phone numbers of length n subject to following
>   constraints: 
>       
>  1.If a number contains a 4, it should start with 4 
>       
>  2.No two consecutive digits can be same 
>       
>  3.Three digits (e.g. 7,2,9) will be entirely disallowed, take as input

Here's my solution:

```
public static void ans(int length, int d1, int d2, int d3) {
    StringBuffer numbers = new StringBuffer();

    for(int i = 0; i < 10 ;i++) {
        if(i != d1 && i != d2 && i != d3) {
            numbers.append(i);
        }
    }
    printNumbers("", numbers.toString(), length);
}

public static void printNumbers(String soFar, String remaining, int length) {
    if(soFar.length() == length) {
        boolean four = false;
        boolean sameAdjDigits = false;

        for(int i = 1; i < soFar.length(); i++) {
            if(soFar.charAt(i-1) == soFar.charAt(i)) sameAdjDigits = true;
            if(soFar.charAt(i) == '4') four = true;
        }

        if(!sameAdjDigits) {
            if(!four || (four && soFar.charAt(0) == '4'))
                System.out.print(soFar + " ");
        }

        return;
    }

    if(soFar.length() < length) {
        for(int i = 0; i < remaining.length(); i++) {
            String newSoFar = soFar + remaining.charAt(i);
            String newRemaining = remaining.substring(0, i) + remaining.substring(i+1);
            printNumbers(newSoFar, newRemaining, length);
        }
    }
}
```

I ran some tests on this code and checked all the printed values. It worked for length 1 and 2. However, I couldn't verify for length > 2 because there were too many numbers.

Can anyone verify if my code runs a correct result? Is there any part of the code that can be improved?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Nitpicks

```
public static void ans(int length, int d1, int d2, int d3) {
```

Any time that I see numbered variables, I want to replace them with a collection.  Since we know that there will be no duplicate values, I'd use a `Set`.

```
public static void generatePhoneNumbers(int length, Set<Character> disallowedDigits) {
```

Also, I find `d` an unclear name, so I switched to `disallowedDigits` which I find clearer.

I switched from `int` to `Character` as you are building a string.  We could just as easily be working with the letters of the alphabet as with numeric digits.

```
StringBuffer numbers = new StringBuffer();
```

This seems an ideal place to use a `StringBuilder`.

```
StringBuilder digits = new StringBuilder();
```

I also changed the name to `digits`, as that tells me that we're talking about one digit at a time rather than multi-digit numbers.

```
            if(!four || (four && soFar.charAt(0) == '4'))
```

You could just as well write

```
            if( ! four || soFar.charAt(0) == '4' )
```

If the string begins with a `4`, then we don't care if none of the rest have a `4`.

### Fulfilling the Problem Statement

```
        String newRemaining = remaining.substring(0, i) + remaining.substring(i+1);
```

This is actively wrong given your problem statement:

> Print all valid phone numbers of length n subject to following constraints:
>   1.  If a number contains a 4, it should start with 4
>   2.  No two consecutive digits can be same
>   3.  Three digits (e.g. 7,2,9) will be entirely disallowed, take as input

From #2, only consecutive digits can't be the same.  So you should not be removing digits from your `remaining` String.  Like length, that will be constant for all calls.

We can rewrite #1 to say:  only numbers that start with `4` can contain `4`.  This effectively gives us different rules for `4` than other values.  Since we're supposed to generate all numbers, I'd suggest that we generate all numbers starting with `4` separately from other numbers.  Fortunately, #3 means that we already need a way to exclude digits from the set.

### ans

Here's how I'd write the method that you called `ans`:

```
private final static char [] DIGITS = "0123456789".toCharArray();

public static void generate(int length, Set<Character> disallowedDigits) {
    Set<Character> allowedDigits = new TreeSet<Character>();

    for ( Character digit : DIGITS ) {
        if ( ! disallowedDigits.contains(digit) ) {
            allowedDigits.add(digit);
        }
    }

    if ( allowedDigits.contains('4') ) {
        printNumbers("4", allowedDigits, length);
        allowedDigits.remove('4');
    }

    for ( Character digit : allowedDigits ) {
        printNumbers("" + digit, allowedDigits, length);
    }
}
```

First, we define a constant to hold the possible digit values.  Then we make a new `Set` that masks out the `disallowedDigits`.  If `4` is allowed, then we generate all the numbers that start with `4` separately.  Then we remove `4` from the `allowedDigits`, as it won't be allowed in any of the other numbers.

### printNumbers

```
    if(soFar.length() == length) {
        boolean four = false;
        boolean sameAdjDigits = false;

        for(int i = 1; i < soFar.length(); i++) {
            if(soFar.charAt(i-1) == soFar.charAt(i)) sameAdjDigits = true;
            if(soFar.charAt(i) == '4') four = true;
        }

        if(!sameAdjDigits) {
            if(!four || (four && soFar.charAt(0) == '4'))
                System.out.print(soFar + " ");
        }

        return;
    }
```

This whole section of code is unnecessary, except for one line (the `print`).  Instead of generating invalid strings and masking them out, just don't generate them in the first place.  That will save all subsequent recursive calls down that path.

```
    if(soFar.length() < length) {
        for(int i = 0; i < allowedDigits.length(); i++) {
            String newSoFar = soFar + allowedDigits.charAt(i);
            String newRemaining = allowedDigits.substring(0, i) + allowedDigits.substring(i+1);
            printNumbers(newSoFar, newRemaining, length);
        }
    }
```

I switched to a `Set` to hold the digits that can be used, so this is going to be a bit different.

```
private static void printNumbers(String soFar, Set<Character> allowedDigits, int length) {
    int lengthSoFar = soFar.length();

    if ( lengthSoFar < length ) {
        Character last = soFar.charAt(lengthSoFar - 1);

        for ( Character digit : allowedDigits ) {
            if ( ! digit.equals(last) ) {
                printNumbers(soFar + digit, allowedDigits, length);
            }
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println(soFar);
    }
}
```

First, we already took care of `4` in our `generate` function.  Here, it will either be in `allowedDigits` or it won't.

Second, we take care of the rule about consecutive digits by simply not starting the recursive generation in that case:  `if ( ! digit.equals(last) ) {`.

I put each number on its own line.  For all but trivial lengths, there are too many numbers to fit on a single line.

Note that `soFar` is the only parameter that changes from call to call.

### Testing

This is a bit difficult.  Because we print the numbers to standard output, we can't run normal unit tests on them.  The simplest way to handle this is to direct the output to a file.  Then we can search the file for values that should or shouldn't be there.

For example, we should never have any of the following sequences:  00, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99, 00.  So search for those in the file.  If they don't exist, then you know that rule is working.

Search for lines containing the `disallowedDigits`.  There shouldn't be any.

Find all the lines in the file that contain a `4` and verify that `4` is the first digit of the number.  On Linux, that might be written something like

```
fgrep '4' < phone_numbers.txt | cut -c1 | sort | uniq -c
```

If there are any values other than `4`, then you can look them up more specifically.

Also search for a few values that you construct, e.g. for a `length` of `8` where `7`, `2`, and `9` are disallowed, `40134568` should be in the list.  Also `86868686` should be there.

Answer (score 2):

You use the value `soFar.length()` multiple times in the `printNumbers()` method, or to be more specific, `2 + soFar.length()` times. You can easily avoid retrieving the value that many times by creating a variable to hold the value:

```
int length = soFar.length();
```

Then replace all the `soFar.length()` with length.

What does `four` exactly mean? Use a more specific and more detailed (but not too much) variable name, such as `hasFour`.

The `return` is completely unnecessary. Instead, use `else-if`:

```
public static void printNumbers(String soFar, String remaining, int length) {
    if(soFar.length() == length) {
        boolean four = false;
        boolean sameAdjDigits = false;

        for(int i = 1; i < soFar.length(); i++) {
            if(soFar.charAt(i-1) == soFar.charAt(i)) sameAdjDigits = true;
            if(soFar.charAt(i) == '4') four = true;
        }

        if(!sameAdjDigits) {
            if(!four || (four && soFar.charAt(0) == '4'))
                System.out.print(soFar + " ");
        }
    } else if(soFar.length() < length) {
        for(int i = 0; i < remaining.length(); i++) {
            String newSoFar = soFar + remaining.charAt(i);
            String newRemaining = remaining.substring(0, i) + remaining.substring(i+1);
            printNumbers(newSoFar, newRemaining, length);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, use braces for ***all*** `if` statements. Instead of:

> ```
> if(soFar.charAt(i-1) == soFar.charAt(i)) sameAdjDigits = true;
> if(soFar.charAt(i) == '4') four = true;
> ```

Do:

```
if(soFar.charAt(i-1) == soFar.charAt(i)) {
    sameAdjDigits = true;
}
if(soFar.charAt(i) == '4') {
    four = true;
}
```

It is more work, but if you don't, horrible bugs may occur.

Otherwise, your code is good.

Comment: IMO, there's nothing wrong with using the `return;`